# C system() function doesn't displays messages

Tags: c, system-calls

In a C program, only if I write

```
system("./a.bin \"$(cat b.txt)\"; read -s -n 1");
```

I can see error messages (for example: "Segmentation fault").
Without the 'read' command my program doesn't show errors; why?
Thank you.

Edit:
OS: Slackware 14.1, compiler: gcc 4.8.2
File a.c contains: `int main() {printf("len = %d\n", strlen(NULL));}`
File p.c contains: `int main() {system("./a.bin \"$(cat b.txt)\"; read -s -n 1");}`
Command "./p.bin" gives:
`sh: line 1:  1177 Segmentation fault      ./a.bin "$(cat b.txt)"`
If we change p.c in `int main() {system("./a.bin \"$(cat b.txt)\"");}`
then executing p.bin no errors appear.

Comment: From manual page: "system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns after the command has been completed". This means you need to use single quotes around your command, if you have more than one there separated by `;`.

Comment: Do you mean: system('./a.bin \"$(cat b.txt)\"; read -s -n 1')? It doesn't work (compiler shows an error).  Or system("./a.bin '$(cat b.txt)'; read -s -n 1")? It doesn't work too (program a.bin gets the string "$(cat b.txt)", not the content of the file). My question was: why without the 'read' command I don't see error messages?

Comment: When using `system("./a.bin \"$(cat b.txt)\"");` I see error messages `cat: b.txt: No such file or directory`
`sh: ./a.bin: No such file or directory`, so, I cannot produce the problem you describe.

Comment: Sorry, I gave very few details.  I tried on Slackware 14 (32 bit).  File "a.c" may be "int main() {printf("len = %d\n", strlen(NULL));}".  File "p.c" may be "int main() {system("./a.bin \"$(cat b.txt)\"; read -s -n 1");}".  Compile with "gcc p.c -o p.bin".  Then execute "./p.bin"